# UIActivityIndicatorView not stopping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I am totally new in iOS developing. Today I learnt what is UIActivityIndicatorView.
Now, I am building a project where I have a table view, I have populated the table using JSON parsing. Now I have added an activity indicator  which will spin upto that time till when the table gets populated.
I have started the activity indicator but it's not stopping. Can you guyz tell me where am I wrong? Thanks in advance. 
This is my code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self fetchData];
self.mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
_mySpinner.hidden = NO;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) fetchData  {

[_mySpinner startAnimating];

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn) {
    _webData = [NSMutableData data];
}
else{
    //error
}

}

#pragma mark Url connection Delegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
// A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
// so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
// Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
// also serves to clear it
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
[_webData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

// The request is complete and data has been received
// You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
// self.data parse

NSDictionary *dict= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.webData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
self.arrDetail = [dict valueForKey:@"loans"];

[self.mySpinner stopAnimating];
self.mySpinner.hidden = YES;

[self.parserTable reloadData];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
// The request has failed for some reason!
// Check the error var

}

#pragma mark Table View Delegates


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];


NSDictionary *locationDict = [[self.arrDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"location"];

UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
lbl1.text = [[self.arrDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];

UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
lbl2.text = [locationDict valueForKey:@"country"];


return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [self.arrDetail count];

}


@end
```

Comment: Where are you adding the spinner to the view? Did you add a `UIActivityIndicatorView ` in interface builder?

Comment: In the tableview. Yes exactly.

Comment: In the code you posted you are create a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in code, but never adding it to a view. If the `mySpinner` is a `IBOutlet` connected in interface builder then there is no need to create the spinner in code.

Comment: I have connected IBOutlet in Interface Builder.

Comment: They why are you assigning a new instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView ` to the outlet? Just remove the `self.mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];` and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are assigning a new instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView` to you outlet property the reference to the one set in InterfaceBuilder is lost.

Just remove :`self.mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have realised my mistake.

Comment: I just don't know why people vote my questions down. :'( And my reputation goes on decreased. :'(

Comment: Most of the time it is because it the question is missing code where you are showing that you attempted to solve the issue yourself. Just specifying requirements without any attempt might be seen as a code request which is frowned up.

Answer (score 2):

To start Activity indicator:

```
[cell.indicater startAnimating];
```

To start Activity indicator:

```
[cell.indicater stopAnimating];
```

Also set properties like shown in screenshot.
[image: Also set properties like shown in screenshot]

Comment: have you understood the question,and gone through the code?

Answer (score 2):

**The Solution**

remove this line from the code

`self.mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite]`

**The Problem**

You haven't shown the property Declaration of `mySpinner`. However from your code I can tell that it is an IBOutlet since you have created a new instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView` and not added it as a subview and you can still see a activity indicator on your view(since it appears and never stops animating).

The reason that it does not stop animating is you call `[_mySpinner startAnimating];` on your IBOutlet. Then you create a new instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView` when you say

`self.mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite]`

now on whatever methods you call on `mySpinner` will be called on an activity indicator which is not on your view but the one you created because you lost your reference to it the moment you created a new `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

Also, since you are new. I would suggest you to use `self.mySpinner` as far as possible and not to use `self` and `_` interchangeably as both are to be used according to need. The reason for is beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize your spinner and then call your connection method like below.

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    _mySpinner.hidden = NO;
    _mySpinner.center = self.view.center;
    [self fetchData];
}
```

...

Comment: The indicator is spinning but after populating the table its not stopping.

Comment: you can remove spinner allocation line if you have connected Interface Builder.

Comment: In your case, you have 2 different spinner, one is at interfacebuilder and started spinnig at your fetchData method, then you create another spinner that is not on the screen. At the end you call stopAnimating but this selector goes to invisible spinner, and your visible spinner continues spinning

Comment: I want to know where to write the method [_myspinner stopAnimating] to stop the indicater when table gets populated.

Comment: just delete 
self.mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite]; line it should work

Comment: @Tirthendu I have mentioned the reason why your code is giving you the problem. Just check my answer